# можно ли менять переменную на префабе?

Tags: unity3d

если я по идеи сделаю так что на префабе в ассетах будет скрипт, и в другой обьект с скриптом поставлю этот префаб, то будет ли включатся и выключатся галочка? или нужно прописывать какие-то строчки чтобы выключать именно на префабе? и будет ли сохранятся значение галочки на префабе, если перейду на другую сцену в плеймоде?

Answer (score 0):

В префабе можно менять значения переменных.

Для этого дважды кликни по префабу, и откроется меню изменения. Дальше заходи в инспектор и меняй значения

Насчёт другой сцены в плеймоде. При создании сцены, создаётся новый объект из префаба.

Т.е. если у тебя в префабе `HP = 100`, а в объекте (на прошлой сцене) `HP = 5`, то у конечного объектаобъекта(на новой сцене) будет `HP = 100`